# Matlab: how to pass a list through a function, return list of answers

Tags: matlab, list, parameter-passing

This should be pretty easy, but I'm new to matlab so forgive me.

I'm making a function function that takes a function y = "some function of x" as an input. y could be a function handle ( let's say y= @(x) x^2 ), or I can y be a symbolic expression (like y = x^2)... Whatever is easier.

I want to run the x list through the function y, and return a list of the calculated y values. so the result should be [1 4 9 16 25]. How would I do this in a function function?

It should look something like this:

```
function myfunc = func(f)
    xlist = [1 2 3 4 5];  %IMPORTANT: in this case, xlist's class is "sym"
    ylist = ... %statement of something like "f(xlist)" goes here*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make *y* as a function handle and call in the m file itself.....

```
y = @(x) x.^2 ;
x = [1 2 3 4 5] ;
y = y(x)
```

If you want to make it a function...either define *y* inside the function or make it as a input as shown below:

```
function out = myfun(x,y)

if ~isa(y,'function_handle')
    error('input t should be a function handle')
end
out = y(x) ;
end


y = @(x) x.^2 ;
x = [1 2 3 4 5] ;
out = myfun(x,y)
```